# Node.js: Reference and modify variables from main js file in exported express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, routes

I am working on the backend for a home automation program I am writing in Node.js, using express as my router. Currently, I have about 50 routes for the frontend to pass information to and from the backend, but these routes are sometimes pretty long, they cover different aspects of the program (querying and updating device states, dealing with activities and 3rd party API such as Google and Plex, etc). I am planning on moving my routes into separate files to increase readability and my ability to maintain the code/routes, but I have run into a problem. Below is an example of one of my routes:

```js
app.route('/api/devices/:deviceID/set/:state').get( async (req, res) => {
    if (!checkRequest(req, res)) return;

    var index = parseInt(req.params.deviceID);
    var device = devices[index];
    if (device === undefined) {
        res.status(404).json({error: 'DeviceNotExist'});
        return;
    }
    var state = req.params.state === '1' ? true : (req.params.state === '0' ? false : undefined);

    let d = await device_tools.setDeviceState(device, state, modules);
    if (d === undefined) {
        res.status(500).json({error: 'DeviceNotResponsive'});
        return;
    }
    let dd = getSendableDevice(d.deviceID);
    res.json(dd);
});
```

As you can see, the route itself depends on the object array 'devices' and an object 'modules', which are variables in my server.js file. However, there are some routes (including the one above) that modify the objects themselves. I have gotten around this previously by requiring that functions outside of server.js have the variables passed to them (as in the line that calls 'setDeviceState' from the module device_tools), but since the routes are not 'functions' in the sense that I can call them, I cannot pass these 'global' (they are not global but I don't know how to describe their scope, maybe top-level?) variables to the API endpoints. Luckily for me, I am in the process of completely refactoring the program anyways (moving away from modules and towards ES6 objects that can encapsulate the static functions in the object class as well as define and abstract the data members of the objects) so I am open to any suggestions, however I prefer to stick as close to vanilla JS as possible, as I do not want to add extra dependencies if I can help it. If my explanation of the problem is not sufficient, I am more than happy to post more code and really break it down if it gets me closer to a solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module that exports the desired **global variables**. The import it in all the modules where younneed them.

Modules are evaluated only once, so all your modules are gonna reference the same variables.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and comment with the results!